# Group By Totals

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

C#, .NET 4.5 LINQ

I have a Persons collection. Each person has a country and the country have a Name properly.

I need to print out an count of the people result that shows:

```
Canada 45
USA 445
Holland 4
```

Not sure how.

```
Source object is like this, fairly simple:
   Person.Country.Name
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
personList.GroupBy(x => x.Country.Name)
           .Select(x => new { CountryName = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
```